# Camera Following The Hero

Tags: python-3.x, scroll, pygame

Camera Following The Hero

I have a bug in pygame where I'm trying to get the Camera to follow the Hero however it appears to make two instances of my game. The top view doesn't have scrolling. The bottom view has scrolling that works the way I want. Both views have my Hero doing identical things (shooting, jumping, moving).  Can anyone help me find and explain why this is happening?

[image: pygame Screen --- has two identical games with different camera views]

**myCamera.py**

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, camera_function, w, h):
        x, y = 0, 0
        self.cameraFrame = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.camera_function = camera_function

    def moveTiles(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.cameraFrame.topleft)

    def updateCamera(self, entity, screenWidth, screenHeight):
        self.cameraFrame = self.camera_function(screenWidth, screenHeight, self.cameraFrame, entity.rect)


def camera_function(screenWidth, screenHeight, camera, target_rect):
    half_width = screenWidth/2
    half_height = screenHeight/2
    left, top, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, width, height = camera
    left, top, _, _ = half_width - left, \
                      half_height - top, \
                      width, \
                      height
    left = min(0, left)
    left = max(-(camera.width - screenWidth), left)
    top = min(0, top)
    top = max(-(camera.height - screenHeight), top)
    return pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height)
```

**myGame.py**

```
    level = [
    "----------------------------------------",
    "-                                      -",
    "-                                      -",
    "-                                      -",
    "-                                      -",
    "-                                      -",
    "-                                      -",
    "-                                      -",
    "----------------------------------------",
]

x, y = 0, 0
for row in level:
    for symbol in row:
        if symbol == "-":
            w, h = TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE
            sprite = mySprites.Entity(x, y, w, h)
            wallSprites.add(sprite)
            allSprites.add(sprite)
        x += TILE_SIZE
    y += TILE_SIZE
    x = 0


def getLevelSize(level):
    width = len(level[0]) * TILE_SIZE
    height = len(level) * TILE_SIZE
    return [width, height]



[levelWidth, levelHeight] = getLevelSize(level)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
camera = myCamera.Camera(myCamera.camera_function,
                         levelWidth, levelHeight)

fps = 60

while not done:
    # Event Handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                hero.moveLeft()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                hero.moveRight()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                hero.aimUp()
                hero.stopMoving()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                hero.aimDown()
                hero.stopMoving()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                w, h = 5, 5
                bullet = mySprites.Bullet(hero.rect.centerx, hero.rect.centery, w, h)
                bullet.setHeading(hero.shootingAngle)
                allSprites.add(bullet)
                bulletSprites.add(bullet)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_j:
                hero.jump()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                hero.moveLeft()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                hero.moveRight()


    # Clear the Screen
    screen.fill(myColors.getColor("white"))

    # Collision Detection
    L = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(hero, wallSprites, False)
    for wall in L:
        if hero.dx > 0:
            hero.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            hero.dx = 0
        elif hero.dx < 0:
            hero.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            hero.dx = 0
        elif hero.dy > 0:
            hero.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            hero.dy = 0
            hero.onGround = True
        elif hero.dy < 0:
            hero.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
            hero.dy = 0

    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bulletSprites, wallSprites, True, False)

    # Draw Sprites
    allSprites.draw(screen)

    # Update Hero
    hero.update()

    # Update Camera
    camera.updateCamera(hero, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)


    for sprite in allSprites:

        if isinstance(sprite, mySprites.Bullet):
            sprite.update()
        screen.blit(sprite.image, camera.moveTiles(sprite))



    # Update Display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Next Frame
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please try to turn your code into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I realized that I was drawing the sprites twice. Once using allSprites.draw() and the other using screen.blit(). By deleting allSprites.draw(), the problem is solved.